# regular expressions to remove parts of string of column starting with a digit

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace the parts of string of a dataframe column. Here is the dataframe below:

```
patientunitstayid,drugname    
144252,1000 ML  -  SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.9 % IV SOLN
142308,3 ML VIAL : INSULIN REGULAR HUMAN 100 UNIT/ML IJ SOLN
```

I want to replace the string which starts with digit and ends with '-  ' or ':  '. Basically want to extract 'SODIUM CHLORIDE' and 'INSULIN REGULAR HUMAN'.
So, I tried this, but didnot work..

```
medications['drugname'] =  medications['drugname'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('^\d.*-\s\s$','', str(x)))
```

Comment: Maybe `medications['drugname'].str.split(r'\s[:-]\s').str[-1]`? Or `df['drugname'].str.extract(r'^\d.*?[:-]\s*([A-Za-z\s]*[A-Za-z])', expand=False)`? What are the exact expected results?

Comment: But which  one? First or second?

Comment: The first one.. But how to remove the last part which starts with an digit?

Comment: So, the second one works, right? Please try. the `.extract` code

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this regular expression:

```
from re import compile
mednamere = compile(r"\d*.*,\d*.*(?:-|:)\s+(.*)\s+\d.*")

#Testing with your examples:
test1 = "144252,1000 ML  -  SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.9 % IV SOLN"
test2 = "142308,3 ML VIAL : INSULIN REGULAR HUMAN 100 UNIT/ML IJ SOLN"
print(mednamere.findall(test1)[0])
print(mednamere.findall(test2)[0])
```